# Average age using months_between()

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have a table with the birth dates and I need to average the people's age. How do I do that? I know I have to use months_between(). Thank you in advance!

Comment: The problem is I only have the birth dates and I need the average age.

Comment: Your post shows zero research effort on your part.  It also does not show that you made any attempt to solve this on your own before posting for someone else to do it for you.

Comment: I did but I don't really understand the structure of the months_between function. I tried to do (TO_DATE('16-05-23',YY-MM-DD'),
  TO_DATE('max('born'),YY-MM-DD') to get the youngest one and this also didn't work, that's my problem.

Comment: If the `born` column is already a date you don't need `TO_DATE`. And the average age calculation depends on your logic: `MONTHS_BETWEEN` returns the number of month including a fractional part, you can average it either directly or first divide by 12 and remove the fractional part before averaging.

Comment: So now I have this (the date format is like this: YY-MM-DD):
select months_between 
  from table
  '16-05-23',
  'max(born)'
from dual;

And it still doesn't work.

Comment: `MONTHS_BETWEEN` is a function with two parameters (dates) like `SELECT MONTHS_BETWEEN(CURRENT_DATE, born)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you think you need `months_between`? You don't (unless you have a very specific and unusual definition of "average age").

Over a long enough period (like 40+ years, say), a person's age in years can be calculated (within a narrow approximation window) as the age in days, divided by 365.25. The age in days is simply a difference between two dates, `SYSDATE` and `DATE_OF_BIRTH` or `BORN`. The first one is provided by the system and the second is in your table. Assuming, that is, that you want age as of today; otherwise change SYSDATE to whatever "as-of" (fixed) date you want to use.

So, something like

```
select [some columns here], AVG(SYSDATE - BORN)/365.25 as avg_age
from   your_table
```

Not clear why you would select `max(born)` from `dual`; surely you didn't call your table `dual`? Nor did you change the standard `dual` table to add your own data to it?

When people ask you what datatype you use for `born` in your tables, what you see on the screen when you query for it is not sufficient; the screen will show a string (it's the only thing a screen shows) and doesn't necessarily reflect what's in the database. To get the proper answer, run `DESCRIBE table_name`; that will show all the columns in `table_name` and their datatype. Note that `DESCRIBE table_name` is a SQL*Plus command (understood by Toad and SQL Developer - whatever you use to communicate with the database), so it doesn't need a `;` or a `/` at the end. Just type it at the prompt and hit `ENTER`.

Good luck!